# how to connect local mongodb with a node.js application using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have been developing full-stack applications for the very first time. I am having troubles in connecting local MongoDB with the node.js application using mongoose. Can some share a detailed method on how to connect it and get is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please google before posting your question here next time!
You can visit the documentation at [mongoosejs.com](https://mongoosejs.com/)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});
```